# Does an action which gives you +2 Advance Civilization require they be used together?

Tags: tiny-epic-galaxies

There are several planets which provide +2 economy / diplomacy (e.g., Padraigin-3110). Do those have to be used to advance a single ship 2 spaces in orbit, or can they be used to advance 2 separate ships 1 space each?

Update: Added a picture showing Padraigin-3110.

[image: Padraigin-3110]

The text of Padraigin-3110 says "Spend 2 culture to advance +2 diplomacy".

Comment: Can you post a picture of Padraign-3110? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the deck for similar cards to `Padraigin-3110`, I came across 1 essentially identical card, `Nakagawakozi` (spend energy to improve economy, rather than spending culture to improve diplomacy, but same general idea). I came across 2 other cards which allow you to regress a ship -2 (`Jorg`) or advance a ship +2 (`Terra-Bettia`).

`Jorg` specifically mentions that you must regress a single ship by -2. `Terra-Bettia` is a bit more ambiguous, but does mention advancing "a ship" +2, implying that it must be a single ship.

In the absence of any clarifications from the designer / manufacturer, and given there are similar cards to `Padraigin` which specifically mention the action must be performed on a single ship, while `Padraigin` does not specifically mention the same, the benefit of `Padraigin-3110` seems to be equivalent to rolling two separate dice, each containing the diplomacy symbol. Similarly, taking the action at `Nakagawakozi` would be equivalent to rolling two economy symbols on the dice. That is, you can advance one ship +2, or two ships +1.

[image: Padraigin and similar]